# AAPT: error: resource not found, but it is present in styles.xml

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, aapt

Full error is

```
AAPT: error: resource style/AppTheme (aka com.mukmenev.android.findjob:style/AppTheme) not found.
```

However `<style name="AppTheme">` is present in `app\src\res\values\styles.xml`

The error points to the generated file

```
app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\debug\processDebugManifest\merged\AndroidManifest.xml
```

which has declarations that I don't have in the main manifest, like

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="19"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<application
    android:name="com.mukmenev.android.findjob.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

So another question is how can it be possible and how to get rid of them?

---

*I've just spent about a week trying to launch this project (given to me by previous developer who is refusing to explain anything) and eliminating errors like links to non-existent resources, but these ones are present and visible by eye.*

---

So how can I make the resources visible for build and what makes the generated manifest look as it looks?

**upd**

After fixing some more errors it came up with several errors like:

```
:app:mergeDebugResources
[string/default_web_client_id] \app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml [string/default_web_client_id] \app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml: Error: Duplicate resources
```

So again, resources get duplicated in a generated file.

**upd 2**

After commenting those out it gives:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.Aapt2Exception: Android resource compilation failed
  Output:  \app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2100: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/navigationMode' with config ''.
  \app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml:2100: error: resource previously defined here.
```

and

```
 Command: C:\gradle-4.6\bin\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows.jar\4627eedc0a8af356ec87f9d6cd62c57c\aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
          -o \
          C:\_com_bucket\komirger-static_branch\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
          C:\_com_bucket\komirger-static_branch\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
  Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.0-4818971-windows Daemon #0
  Output:  C:\gradle-4.6\bin\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\5e49e71c0795be6393bc5ece684619fc\res\values\values.xml:71:5-86:1291: AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/navigationMode' with config ''.

  C:\gradle-4.6\bin\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-26.1.0.aar\5e49e71c0795be6393bc5ece684619fc\res\values\values.xml:71:5-86:1291: AAPT: error: resource previously defined here.
```

I tried invalidating caches in Android Studio but with no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Resources should be under `app\src\main\res\`. Where are your Java files?

Comment: @TheWanderer app/src/main/java

Comment: Move the `res` folder under `main`.

Comment: @TheWanderer thanks, started getting another bunch of error (duplicated resources in some xml files), I'll fix them and try again

Comment: @TheWanderer updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to remove `default_web_client_id` from `res/values/strings.xml`

and let the Goggle Services Plugin add that string resource instead.

then it most likely can generate `R` and the style might be found then.

Comment: [answered 10 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52863564/4409113) - [answered 7 mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52863608/4409113) Looks duplicate answer.

Comment: not exactly a duplicate, while explaining why it happens and what to do about it.

Comment: it kind of helped, but gave another error, updated my question

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer because it suggests completely removing the key from `strings.xml` which worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem this week after updating Android Studio to the latest version, only difference being aapt2 created problems with all my resources, starting from colors.xml and when I pasted the content from a different project, the problem moved to the drawables, etc. It seemed to be happening only in new projects though, so I was sure it had nothing to do with previously written code. You should try seeing if you can build new projects, maybe the problem is the same for you.

I tried a lot of things to fix this, but the only thing that seemed to do the trick for me was a clean reinstallation of Android Studio. I made sure to erase everything related to the application besides my projects and reinstalled from scratch. After that the project built without a glitch.

Hope this helps!

PS. Make sure to check under all your drives to avoid any slip ups as in my case Android Studio was installed in E:// while android data like .gradle was "hidden" under C:// which gave me the option to reinstall with previous settings a couple of times leading to no change.

Comment: please check the question update - does it fit the situation you described?

Comment: After upd1 and upd2 I notice the same patterns as the ones I saw in the problem I was facing, it was all coming from the .gradle file

Answer (score 1):

> values.xml: Error: **Duplicate resources**

There are still duplicate resources in `strings.xml`. Remove the duplicate one and it will work fine after that.

Id-name: `string/default_web_client_id`

> `\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml` [`string/default_web_client_id`]
>   `\app\build\generated\res\google-services\debug\values\values.xml`:
>   ***Error: Duplicate resources***

If the path is correct and everything is in the right place, remove `build` folder and try to rebuild project.

Comment: removed duplicates, got another error, updated my question